# failed to query solr using '*:*'

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

getting an error :

> Failed to query Solr using '*:*': Failed to connect to server at `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/solr/select/?fq=django_ct%3A%28jobpost.jobpost%29&rows=1&q=%2A%3A%2A&start=0&wt=json&fl=%2A+score'`, are you sure that URL is correct? Checking it in a browser might help: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /solr/select/?fq=django_ct%3A%28jobpost.jobpost%29&rows=1&q=%2A%3A%2A&start=0&wt=json&fl=%2A+score (Caused by : [Errno 111] Connection refused)

this is my haystack connection:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/solr'
    },
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's the problem with my code?

Comment: did you try running your search in your browser? check that the addresses match... its been a while since I worked on solr, but I remember clearly that between `/solr/` and `/select/` we had something else (the instance name, for example)

Comment: it says page not found

Comment: it is not connecting to server..i don't know what t do

Comment: how are you running solr? using jetty? have you got a webserver up? that may be the problem... don't expect stuff to work out of the box just because you installed it

Comment: Did you even start it?

Comment: started it like java -jar start.jar

Comment: Based on how you are starting Solr it is probably running on the default port of 8983. Try accessing `http://localhost:8983/solr` from a browser.

Answer (score 2):

May be solr is running on apache tomcat which uses port 8080 so you can try 127.0.0.1:8080/solr
or you can check on which port apache tomcat is running

Answer (score 0):

Try using your real IP instead of the loopback or localhost:8000